# How to display precisely the decimal digits of a double in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers, double

> **Problem**
>   Given two integers a, b, a < b. Display its decimal expansion. You will print the decimal expansion of integer quotient given, stopping just as the expansion terminates or just as the repeating pattern is to repeat itself for the first time. If there is a repeating pattern, you will say how many of digits are in the repeating pattern.
>
> **Sample Input**
>   3 7
>   345 800
>   112 990
>   53 122
>
> **Sample Output**
>   .428751
>   The last 6 digits repeat forever.
>   .43125
>   This expansion terminates.
>   .113
>   The last 2 digits repeat forever.
>   .4344262295081967213114754098360655737704918032786885245901639
>   The last 60 digits repeat forever.

*Note: This problem is original from the ProgFest programming contest.*

The algorithm for this problem is not difficult if we apply these three theorems:
[image]

However, the problem that I'm facing is the rounding-off when calculating alpha using the recursive formula given in Theorem 1. The display function is defined as follows:

```
void displayFraction( int n, int d, int length ) {
    std::cout << ".";
    double alpha = static_cast<double>( n ) / d;
    for( int i = 1; i <= length; ++i ) {
        int c = std::floor( 10.0 * alpha );
        alpha = 10.0 * alpha - c;
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

And my output was:

```
.4344 2622 9508 1967 3732 7807 5683 6291 4025 7835 3881 8359 3750 0000 0000 0
```

where the problem output was:

```
.4344 2622 9508 1967 2131 1475 4098 3606 5573 7704 9180 3278 6885 2459 0163 9
```

As you can see, it was correct up to the 16th digit. So my question is, how I can prevent the truncating digits when performing the calculation in this particular situation? Any idea?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Asking how to get better precision to solve rounding errors seems valid enough?

Comment: I don't understand why 2 downvotes? At least give me some comments so that I can improve my answer if you dislike my question.

Comment: You can't use floating-point numbers for this. [Double only has precision of about 16 digits.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: @Asgeir: Thank you. Any suggested algorithm?

Comment: Theorem 1 _is_ the algorithm. It's just your implementation of it that is wonky. Remember, division in integer math automatically does a floor for you…

Comment: I'd guess the downvotes were because they superficially thought it was homework, but you didn't mark it as such. It's actually for a context. Some people have negative feelings towards unmarked homework questions.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: Your hint is very helpful. I can just perform the calculation on the fraction and in fact I got the exact result ;) Thank you.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I often vote after reading the question or answer several times. How could someone just scheme over a question and vote right away like that? It was just ridiculous!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `double` doesn't have infinite amounts of precision, but instead can only manage about 16 decimal digits worth. Which is where you run into trouble (funny, that!) as the fundamental lack of information in the input `double` shows up.

You need to find a way of tackling the problem that will keep getting closer to the answer as you get more digits out of it. That means you'll need to think much more about Theorem 3, and also work on writing your code in terms of rationals instead of floating point.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I applied Theorem 3 to find the pre-period length as well as period length. However, I can't think of a better way to express it as rational rather than floating point number.

Comment: Really? By thinking in terms of rationals (and just using ordinary ints) I've solved this little puzzle and checked it against your sample in the time between the answer and this response.

Comment: Yes, I used Theorem 3 to calculate the pre-period length, and period length, which is the third parameter in my `displayFraction` function.

Answer (score 2):

Use a bignum library like [gmp](http://gmplib.org/). There's only so much information you can pack into a double.

Comment: Thank you, still, I can't use any external libraries during the contest.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want an arbitrary precision library

Something like the [gnu MP bignum](http://gmplib.org/), although other flavours are [available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)

Comment: Thank you, however I don't think this solution is feasible because the problem was from a contest which limits only to standard C++ libraries.

Comment: @Chan - then you either have to be clever or you will have to reinvent the wheel a little bit.  (the gnu project is open source - you can see how they do it)

Comment: That's right. I forgot that I can use their idea because it is open-source. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tom: That's using a thermonuclear device to swat a fly. It'll work, but it's _so_ excessive for this task.

Comment: Not sure if it will work, actually. bignum's have countably finite precision (obviously limited by available memory). Yet, as the examples show, we're dealing here with numbers that have no finite representation.

Comment: @Donal, @MSalters - Your right, this answer should be downvoted.  I answered the question without reading it properly (in fact I only read the last line properly that said their was a problem with finite precision.)  It seems I missed the point entirely.